# SQL server reporting: subreport doesnt handle page breaks properly when exported to excel

Tags: .net, excel, pdf, reporting-services

I am running into a problem where I have a main report which calls sub report; the sub report contains data in matrix control. I am trying to export each week's data on a separate sheet on Excel, but excel only displays 1 week's data instead of 4 weeks. The same sub report, when exported to PDF, shows data weekly on separate pages, but in excel it doesn't. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated (I tried to insert page breaks on matrix and list which is parent to matrix that contains desired data)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, welcome to SO.

My first suggestion would be to see if you can use Sql Server 2008 R2 with its new Report Parts, This eliminates the need for sub-reports in a lot of cases. Besides that, I think you might be out of luck.

Comment: i see your point but, according to requirement i have to stick to sqlserver 2000 :)

Comment: Hmm... You might try extracting your matrix out of your sub-report if possible. In my experience with Reporting Services, getting random features like this to work correctly required me writing a few 'hacks' to get it the end result to look correctly.